# Downloading xml file from a url using c#

Tags: c#, xml

I would like to download the document on this ("http://www.ploscompbiol.org/article/info%3Adoi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pcbi.1002244") page as an xml file. I have tried webclient.downloadfile() but i got errors. can anyone suggest how to go about it using c#.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like this:  **(note the URL I'm using...)**

```
public static string DownloadString(string address) 
{
    string text;
    using (var client = new WebClient()) 
    {
        text = client.DownloadString(address);
    }
    return text;
}

private static void Main(string[] args) 
{    
    var xml = DownloadString(@"http://www.ploscompbiol.org/article/fetchObjectAttachment.action?uri=info%3Adoi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pcbi.1002244&representation=XML");            
    File.WriteAllText("blah.xml", xml);
}
```