# How to download xml file from url

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I want to download the xml file on button or link click as i am using Gridview in the web form when click on button or link it will open the xml file on new tab as i want to download it.I am using http url(eg. http://SomeName/XmlFiles/1554263.xml)

Comment: Or if that duplicate is not enough  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17034396/downloading-xml-file-from-a-url-using-c-sharp shows saving result to file... (obviously you already done this research yourself, but for some reason did not put results of your investigations into the post - for future questions make sure to provide that information in the question. Otherwise post may be downvoted due to lack of *demonstrated research*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might do the trick for you

```
using (System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    client.DownloadFile("http://SomeName/XmlFiles/1554263.xml", "some.xml");
}
```

[WebClient.DownloadFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe.aspx) downloads to a local file data from the URI specified by in the address parameter. This method blocks while downloading the resource. To download a resource and continue executing while waiting for the server's response, use one of the DownloadFileAsync methods.

**Edit**

```
SaveFileDialog savefile = new SaveFileDialog(); 
// set a default file name
savefile.FileName = "unknown.xml";
if (savefile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    using (System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient())
    {
        client.DownloadFile("http://SomeName/XmlFiles/1554263.xml", savefile.FileName);
    }
}
```

Comment: i already tried this but i need to save it on specific path provided by user so i want a save dialog and download at that path,how do i achieve that.

Comment: how do i open save dialog for this file downloading

Comment: its not working, may be because Save Dialog is the property of winform

Comment: I am working on webform asp.net

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.

```
using System.Net;

string xyzstring;
try
{
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    xyzstring= wc.DownloadString("http://www.example.com/somefile.xml");
}
catch (WebException ex)
{

    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```